# performance observer not working with react route change

Tags: reactjs

Im using the performance Observer api and it works in the original route but does not work with changes I tried many different ways but cant get it to work.

Original Route

```
import React, { useEffect, Component } from 'react';
import ContextState from './context_state_config';
import history from './utils/history';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
import './App.css'

ReactGA.initialize('');




var observer = new PerformanceObserver(list => {
    list.getEntries().forEach(entry => {
      // Display each reported measurement on console
      if (console) {
        console.log(entry);
      }
    })
  });
  observer.observe({entryTypes: [
                                  'navigation',
                                  // 'paint',
                                  // 'resource',
                                  // 'mark',
                                  // 'measure',
                                  // 'frame',
                                  // 'longtask'
                                ]})


history.listen((location) => {

    let observer = new PerformanceObserver(list => {
        list.getEntries().forEach(entry => {
          // Display each reported measurement on console
            console.log('ffff');
        })
      });
    observer.observe({entryTypes: [
                                    'navigation',
                                    'paint',
                                    // 'resource',
                                    // 'mark',
                                    // 'measure',
                                    // 'frame',
                                    // 'longtask'
                                  ]});
});


const App = () => {

    return(
      <div className="App">
        React
        <ContextState />
      </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Another Route:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as ACTIONS from '../store/actions/actions';
import * as FormReducer from '../store/reducers/form_reducer';
import Context from '../utils/context';
//
// var observer = new PerformanceObserver(list => {
//     list.getEntries().forEach(entry => {
//       // Display each reported measurement on console
//       if (console) {
//         console.log(entry);
//       }
//     })
//   });
//   observer.observe({entryTypes: [
//                                   'navigation',
//                                   'paint',
//                                   // 'resource',
//                                   // 'mark',
//                                   // 'measure',
//                                   // 'frame',
//                                   // 'longtask'
//                                 ]});

const HooksForm1 = () => {
  useEffect(() =>{
    let observer = new PerformanceObserver(list => {
        list.getEntries().forEach(entry => {
          // Display each reported measurement on console
          console.log(entry);
        })
      })
    observer.observe({entryTypes: ['paint']})
  }, [])
  const context = useContext(Context)
...
```

As mentioned its working when I initially load the page on the first load but When I do a route change nothing is printed to the console.

I would like to have it run automatically on each page change.

It also works when I load to another page that is not the original app.js page.

for example I went directly on the /hooks form route and reloaded the page. After reloading the page the navigation timing api printed the correct result but its still not working on subsequesnt page changes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone it was my mistake but the code posted above does work,.

My problem was I was testing the wrong entries: navigation and paint. These two entries are only supposed to work on the initial page load, because of the fact react is a single page app.

First paint really does mean *First* Paint

After testing out other entries like mark and measure it works as expected.

Comment: I think you should point out that there is still no "non-custom" way to capture client side React routing using the API